# How to work php front controller using .htaccess?

Tags: php, .htaccess, front-controller

I did front controller using the query string.

Ex:

- http://host/controller.php?display=main,
- http://host/controller.php?display=contact_form

But I need to do it without using query string.

Comment: so, what actually do you want?

Comment: @Chasing Death: In the I mentioned example I catch main from quary string and include main.php. Now I need without getting "main" from the quary string include the main.php. I tried this wit this tutorial. http://onlamp.com/pub/a/php/2004/07/08/front_controller.html?page=1

Comment: Actually I need to call controller in indirect way.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

in .htaccess

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine on
    RewriteRule    (.*) controller.php    [L]
 </IfModule>
```

This will reroute everything to controller.php; so you can access it like:

```
http://host/main
http://host/contact_form
```

Then in controller.php you have to parse $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] to extract passed arguments.

Hope that helps..

Comment: Thanks, this is really good to have. I don't like having to use a bloated PHP controller library just for clean URLs.